# autoit +selanium on jenkins does not work

Tags: selenium, jenkins, autoit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NuB6.png)I have a selenium test implement for web application and implemented autoit to do a folder upload to my application. This folder upload initiates a chrome popup warning which has no title but 2 buttons "Upload" and "Cancel" (default selected).  The folder upload is in the control of my application and has title for the popup window. So I could see controlfocus worked on upload folder popup even when my test was deployed on jenkins. But it does not click on the Chrome popup warning

```
      #include <WinAPIFiles.au3>
      ControlFocus("Select Folder to Upload","","Edit1")
      ControlSetText("Select Folder to Upload","","Edit1","<Myfolder Path>")
      sleep(4000)

      ControlClick("Select Folder to Upload","","Button1")
      sleep(4000)
      ;this is for the popup warning from chrome 
      ControlFocus("[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]","","Edit1")
      Send("{LEFT}") <===== this and below does not ever work on jenkins but works on local 
         execution
         Send("{ENTER}")
         ;sleep(10000)

         exit(0)


         my selenium code has 
         String filepath = ".\\uploadfile.bat";
          Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( filepath );

         uploadfile.bat is ....
         START /wait c:\AutoIT\uploadfld.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

As first step run yours AutoIt script, and just after that click the HTML element using selenium.

Do not try to run AutoIt script after clicking the HTML element in selenium, as this stops your selenium because browser waits for file selection.

And as I said in one other cases (question which I answer some time ago), there should be other possibilities to do that without AutoIt, even without invoking the pop up window.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do want to wait for the autoscript to upload the folder and then accept the default popup (attached the pic as a link to my post) that comes from chrome. I have tried without autoit and using robot  it works when I execute on the local machine not from a jenkins job.